# How to get data from memory if available in obj.__dict__?

Tags: python, class, properties, instance-variables

I have a class something like :

```
def compute():
    # CPU savy task
    return some_value

def compute_other():
    # CPU savy task
    return some_value

class myclass:

    @property
    def value:
        # return if already computed => What can be done ?
        computed_value = compute()
        return computed_value

    @property
    def other:
        # return if already computed => What can be done ?
        computed_value = compute_other()
        return computed_value

ob = myclass()
print ob.value, ob.other
print ob.value, ob.other
print ob.value, ob.other
```

How can I intercept the method call to `value` and `other` and return the values if already available.

Can `__getattribute__(self,name)` be used to intercept any `property` and lookup if already available in `self.__dict__` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a memoization decorator and just apply it to your class:

```
@memoize
@property
    def value:
        # return if already computed => What can be done ?
        computed_value = compute()
        return computed_value
```

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize

Comment: Shouldn't you memoize first? Besides, this contains syntax errors.

Comment: Also, this is subtly but significantly different than what the OP is actually trying to do.  This is memorizing a return value from a method that takes arguments.  Such an implementation is overkill when all that is wanted to a way to lazy load and cache static class members.

Comment: Almost seems like what I was looking for except `memoize` decorator package is still a mystry

Answer (score 0):

Using **getattribute** is over-complicating this problem.  Simple **getattr** or even just structuring your property getter differently will work better and not leave you with the unintended consequences that result when using **getattribute**.

You should follow the form:

```
    @property
    def x:
        try:
            return self._x
        except AttributeError:
            self._x = foo()
```

alternatively:

```
    @property
    def x:
        if '_x' not in self.__dict__:
            self._x = foo()
        return self._x
```

finally, if you want to get fancier:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    getter = '_get_%s' % name
    try:
        value = getattr(self, getter)(self)
        setattr(self, name, value)
        return value
    except AttributeError:
        raise AttributeError('No getter defined for %s.' % name)

def _get_x(self):
    return foo()
```

This allows you to define any arbitrary new variable in the class by just writing another `_get_var()` method for it.  Less boilerplate is usually good, unless you only will ever have one or two of these types of values attached to the class.